# How to reload scripts after canceling print function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing

So I got this website where I dynamically create elements with javascript. Once a user is done creating the element he wants he can click a print button. This will fire the following javascript function:

```
function printContent() {

var restore = document.body.innerHTML;

var printcontent = document.getElementById('h').innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;

window.print();

document.body.innerHTML = restore;

}
```

So far, so good. But when someone cancels the printing it returns visually to its previous state but the scripts are not loaded. I tested this by giving an alert in my external js documents. The alert is never fired when returning from a print command. I know that the problem is the variable restore. It just returns a string.

My question: how do I get my js files to reload again while keeping the body of the document in the state of restore when a print command is canceled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `window.onafterprint` event implemented in firefox and IE, it's not cross-browser though [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onafterprint)

Edit:
I found [this](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) which should be cross-browser compatible:

```
(function() {
  var beforePrint = function() {
      console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
  };
  var afterPrint = function() {
      console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
  };

  if (window.matchMedia) {
      var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
      mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
          if (mql.matches) {
              beforePrint();
          } else {
              afterPrint();
          }
      });
  }

  window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
  window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

Comment: Well, after some tests I decided to give up. It works but is definetely not perfect and does not work for my scripts. I will stick to jQuery plugins. Would have been nice to write a clean javascript printing script though. I guess I will try that another day when I have some time.